# Encoding Image to Base64 to MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, base64

Below is the Python code that am using to try to get this done.

I am trying to take an image and upload that to my MongoDB as base64.  This issue is that whenever I try to put it into MongoDB it is giving me a different string.

I added the line of code to output enc_file to a text document, and that is the correct Base64 which can then be converted back to an image.  The issue is that I am getting the output in the image below in my MongoDB Database.

[image]

```
import os
import base64
import pymongo

def checkImage(file_name):
    if file_name.lower().endswith(('.png', '.jpg', '.jpeg', '.tiff', '.bmp', '.gif')):
        return True
    return False

def checkFile(file_name):
    if(os.path.exists(file_name)):
        return True
    return False

def convert64(file_name):
    image_file = open(file_name, "rb")
    bs64_str = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())
    return bs64_str

conn_str = "--"

connection = pymongo.MongoClient(conn_str, serverSelectionTimeoutMS=5000)
db = connection.test
file_meta = db.file_meta

def main():
    while(True):
        file_name = input("Enter the image name to upload: ")
        # check if the file exists or not in our folder
        if checkFile(file_name):
            # verify that the file is an image file
            if checkImage(file_name):
                # print(convert64(file_name))
                enc_file = convert64(file_name)
                coll = db.testcollection
                
                with open('base64.txt', 'wb') as f:
                    f.write(enc_file)
                    
                coll.insert_one({"filename": file_name, "file": enc_file, "description": "test"})
                break;
        else:
            print("Please enter a valid image file")

main()
```

I am expecting the output from the text document to be the same output that is inserted into my Mongo Database.

Comment: *it is giving me a different string.* - it's not just different, it's a Base64 encoded version of the already Base64 encoded string, (double encoding) Take the Base64 encoded string of the jpg image `/9j/4AAQ...` and encode it again, you'll get: `LzlqLzRBQVE...`. I don't see why or where it happens.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this now as well.

You are turning the image into base64 and it seems mongodb does it as well, that is why you are seeing a different string -- you are getting a base64 of a base64.

```
import bson
from bson import Binary

with open(image_location, "rb") as img_file:
    my_string = Binary(img_file.read())

my_collection.insert_one({"_id": bson_id_image, "Image": my_string })
```